# Flutter: Best practice for nested async HTTP calls

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to load the result of two Http requests into a list-item  (the second request is a get detail about the first request result item). 
The first request gets a list of cryptocurrencies. 
The second request collects more information about that currency.

[image]

The reason why I want to accomplish this in two separate requests is,

1. the data is on different sources.
2. after I got the list of currencies I want to show a process circle, which means "stay calm, details are loading"

What I already tried is ;

- One stateful-widget with two methods ( both are calling setState)  it was catastrophic. Endless loop.
- **One base stateful-widget and a second child stateful-widget in the build method. Worked but whenever I scroll up or down, the list re-renders its items, and the child stateful-widget makes the same getPrice HTTP request again and again.**
- One inherited-widget and one stateless-widget.  Had to use the context for both of the HTTP request methods. It caused endless loops again.

Currently, a part of my Brain yells "Redux is the only way to handle this in a proper way"

Do you have any suggestions how to handle this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by _endless loop_ ? You most likely did something wrong. BTW I never needed redux in flutter with over 2y of experience

Comment: Also, this question can be classified as "opinion based". Which should be avoided on stackoverflow as there's no finite answer.

Comment: I fired setState in the getCurrencyList function and in the getCurrencyDetail function. Whereas I called getCurrencyDetail always in the listView.builder. I will try to chain right after the getList request before I set the state.

Answer (score 0):

```
void getOwnedCoins() async {
CoinsList cList = await ResourceCoins().list();
setState(() {
  list = cList;
  items = cList.result.length;
});
getCoinSummary(cList);
}

void getCoinSummary(CoinsList coins) {
coins.result.forEach((Coin coin) async {
  CoinSummary cs = await ResourceCoinSummary().summary(market: {'market': 'btc-' + coin.currency});
  coin.summary = cs;

  setState(() {
    list = coins;
  });
});
}
```

That's how I solved it. My mistake was to call the **getCoinSummary** in the ListView.builder. However, I feel not comfortable with that setState in **getCoinSummary**. Every time I get details from server I re-render the whole list. Is it how it should be?